# Catching SIGVTALRM signal, cp

Tags: c++, signals

I am trying to catch a `SIGVTALRM` sent by `setitimer`, and I have no idea why it doesn't work. here's my code:

```
void time(int time) {
    cout << "time" << endl;
    exit(0);
}

int main(void) {
    signal(SIGVTALRM, time);
    itimerval tv;
    tv.it_value.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    tv.it_interval.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
    setitimer(ITIMER_VIRTUAL, &tv, NULL);
    while (true) {
        cout << "waiting" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason it never invokes `time()` - is it because it doesn't catch the signal or because the signal wasn't sent in the first place I don't know.

It should be pretty simple. Any ideas? thanks

Comment: What you mean with "it doesn't work" ? It's a little general :)

Comment: True, I've edited the question. It never enters time(), so I think it probably doesn't catch the signal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it is not working?

Everything looks fine to me. May be you are not waiting enough. Since you are printing the string `waiting` inside the loop and you are using the virtual timer, as a result the clock ticks only when the process runs (IO time not included). So in reality your timer might expire after several (>5) seconds.

Try commenting out the printing part.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to `signal` function. As mentioned in http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages//precise/en/man2/signal.2.html:

```
The  behavior  of  signal()  varies  across UNIX versions, and has also varied historically across different versions of Linux.  Avoid its use: use sigaction(2) instead.
```

So the main method should be:

```
int main(void) {
    itimerval tv;
    struct sigaction sa;

    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sa.sa_handler = timer_handler;
    if (sigaction(SIGVTALRM, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        printf("error with: sigaction\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    tv.it_value.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    tv.it_interval.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
    setitimer(ITIMER_VIRTUAL, &tv, NULL);

    while (true) {
        cout << "waiting" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```